# using f.select, undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok so i am tring to list my genres in a f.select form and I am getting an error. I have look everywhere and i am just not understanding what i am doing differently. when I enter rails c and type `g = Genre.all` it lists all genres then `g.map` out puts `=> #<Enumerator: ...>`

Error:

```
undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
```

View Page:

```
<%= f.fields_for :genres do |g| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= g.label :genre %>
    <%= g.select :genres, @genres.map {|g| g.name} %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def create
  @song = Song.new(params[:song])
  @genres = Genre.all
  if @song.save
    redirect_to player_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign `@genres` variable in `new` action too:

```
def new
  @genres = Genre.all
end
```